# Powershell output destroys formatting and produces gobbledegook

Tags: powershell

I've got all the information I need in a nice powershell table after running

```
get-mailbox | get-mailboxstatistics | ft displayname, totalitemsize
```

However the information gets changed to a single line of numbers and letters when I go to export it using:

```
| Export-Csv "C:\MailboxList.csv"
```

Is there a way to export the table as it's shows in the powershell shell?

Comment: Change the `ft` to a `Select-Object` and that should help you out...

Comment: Also recommend using -NoTypeInformation Switch with the Export-CSV cmdlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comment from Shaneis, this issue occurs because the `ft` (`Formt-Table`) cmdlet changes the object type and as such you cannot then use `Export-Csv` after it.

You should instead use `Select-Object` to filter your results down to the properties you want to output and then use `Export-CSV` after this:

```
get-mailbox | get-mailboxstatistics | select displayname, totalitemsize | Export-Csv "C:\MailboxList.csv"
```

Generally you use the `Format-Table` cmdlet as the last cmdlet when you want to output a nicely formatted table to the screen (although you can also send this output to a file with `Out-File` and it will appear in the file exactly as it does on screen).

To understand this issue in more detail, I recommend reading [this article about how you should filter left, format right](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2009.09.windowspowershell.aspx).

Comment: didn't know about the `Out-File` part, thanks for the knowledge!